# How do I make embedded videos in Weebly autostart?

Tags: weebly

I would like embedded videos on my Weebly site to autostart when the user loads the page.

I do not see this feature in the Weebly interface.

Comment: I found something online, so I'll just put it here, since I can't test it: you have to add `<param name="AutoStart" value="true">` and `autostart="1"` to the `<embed>` tag.

Comment: Found it [here](http://tiaacosta.weebly.com/embed-video.html); in case it helps.

Comment: Auto-starting videos are a pox.